# Creating custom XML from XPaths stored in text file

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

I have a text file that contains xpaths from some other (source) xml file. But, now I want to use those xpaths to create my custom xml file .

Below are files as above :-

Source.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="abc.html">HomePage</a>
        <form id="my form" name="form 22" class="forms">
            <table id="table1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           <a> UserName </a> 
                           <input type="textbox" id="username" name="uname" class="login"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                         <td>
                           <a> Password </a> 
                           <input type="textbox" id="password" name="pwd" class="login"/>
                        </td>  
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Generated xpaths using java stored in text file:-

source-xpaths.txt

```
//html[1]/head[1]/title[1]="My Page"


//html[1]/body[1]/a[1][@href='abc.html']
//html[1]/body[1]/a[1]="HomePage"


//html[1]/body[1]/form[1][@id='my form']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1][@name='form 22']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1][@class='forms']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1][@id='table1']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/a[1]="UserName"


//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/input[1][@type='textbox']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/input[1][@id='username']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/input[1][@name='uname']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/input[1][@class='login']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/a[1]="Password"


//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/input[1][@type='textbox']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/input[1][@id='password']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/input[1][@name='pwd']
//html[1]/body[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/input[1][@class='login']
```

Now, I want my custom xml to be formed from this xpaths as below:-

```
<My Page>
</My Page>

<HomePage>
    <href>abc.html</href>
</HomePage>

<UserName>
    <type>textbox</type>
    <id>username</id>
    <name>uname</name>
    <class>login</class>
</UserName>

<Password>
    <type>textbox</text>
    <id>password</id>
    <name>pwd</name>
    <class>login</class>
</Password>
```

//etc etc....

In short, I want all text in  or  tags to be parent node and all corresponding attributes to be their child nodes.

How can I create custom xml in java?

Any help is appreciated... :)

Comment: till now ..I am able to generate source-xpaths.txt file..I want help in last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to apply an [XSL transformation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) to your Source.xml file.  An XSL file makes use of XPath expressions such as yours.

Java supports XSL transformations using the [javax.xml.transform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html) package:

```
File sourceFile = new File("Source.xml");
File customXmlFile = new File("custom.xml");

Source source = new StreamSource(sourceFile);
Result result = new StreamResult(customXmlFile);

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION. "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT. "yes");

transformer.transform(source, result);
```